# Error Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, timeout, webdriver, protractor

I have a problem with my Protractor tests. My angular app uses $timeout to continuously poll something from a server. Unfortunately this lead to the following error message when I'm running my tests:

```
 There was a webdriver error: Error Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protrac
tor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
```

How can I handle such continuously polling timeouts? Setting the `browser.ignoreSynchronization` to `false` is not a good solution in my case (when I do that I have to insert a lot of `browser.sleep()`)

Switching from $timeout to $interval as suggested [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) is currently not possible in my application. Increasing the timeout is also not possible (as I said the service is continuously polling something from the server)

Is there a possibility to change the `waitForAngular` routine so that my test won't timeout?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

From [protractor's documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md):

> Before performing any action, Protractor asks Angular to wait until
>   the page is synchronized. This means that all timeouts and http
>   requests are finished. If your application continuously polls $timeout
>   or $http, it will never be registered as completely loaded. You should
>   use the $interval service ([interval.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/interval.js)) for anything that polls
>   continuously (introduced in Angular 1.2rc3).

Comment: Is there no other way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Same boat with you.

We've seen a lot of posts discussing `sleep()`, `waitForAngular()`and `browser.ignoreSynchronization`.

I agree with you that it is not a good idea to set: `ignoreSynchronization = true`, since it forces us to wait on each async process manually.

Some suggested using `sleep()` and then `waitForAngular()` together like this:

```
browser.sleep(10000);
browser.waitForAngular();
```

I do not really understand why sometimes `waitForAngular()` fails to wait for the page synchronization to complete, and this "double waiting" code did work.

Please see if it works in your case.

Answer (score 1):

add allScriptsTimeout: 50000 in protractor configuration file

```
exports.config = {
    ...
    allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
    ...
};
```

or at least this solved my issue

Answer (score -1):

Changing allScriptsTimeout to a greater value than 11000 thousand fixed my problem

> Timed out waiting for Protractor ...

In node_modules/protractor/lib/configParser.js, changed:

`allScriptsTimeout: 25000`

Comment: You should not change the default values in the module's internals... Change it in your own config file. See the comment below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36353189/672870).