# Protractor browser.getCurrentUrl() is not working on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, gulp-protractor

I have just started using protractor for e2e testing of an Angular single page application. I have started the test with login page. This the test I wrote for fail case

**Tesr Case 1**

```
  it('Login with wrong email', function() {
    loginPage.get();
    loginPage.setEmail('xxxxx@xxxx.com');
    loginPage.setPassword('12345678');
    loginPage.submit()

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(loginPage.appUrl + '/#/login')
  })
```

The above code works **perfectly**. I am testing login failure with url, if the url haven't changed consider it as a failure. **Q1**)Is this the right approach? should I check for the error message, I have seen an example like this, so testing login failure with url.

**Test Case 2**

This is where I am getting the error, test case to check the successful login.

```
it('Login with correct email', function() {
  loginPage.get();
  loginPage.setEmail('YYYY@YYYY.YY');
  loginPage.setPassword('12345678');
  loginPage.submit()
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(loginPage.appUrl + '/#/home')
})
```

The above test case also works perfectly if I don't use `browser.getCurrentUrl()`, I am getting the following error when I use `getCurrentUrl`, this `loginPage.submit()` is a successful login attempt and redirects to another route.

> Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md. The following tasks were pending

I have googled this issue and found lot of solution and none of them seems to work.

**Tried Out solutions**

1. Added `allScriptsTimeout`, `getPageTimeout` to protractor configuration file.
2. Added `defaultTimeoutInterval` to configuration file
3. Found following **SO** questions [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009256/protractor-e2e-tests-login-redirection), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809336/angularjs-protractor-how-do-you-test-an-ajax-login-call) and this github [issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1133), tried all three and none seems to be working
4. When I googled with the `timeout` error message, I found this SO questions [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873680/error-timed-out-waiting-for-protractor-to-synchronize-with-the-page-after-11-sec),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741896/protractor-times-out-waiting-for-sync-with-page-when-using-resource), I tried all which is not working

Basically all the solutions says to use `wait`, `sleep`, `waitForAngular`. I tried all in `thenable` fashion, since all returns promise. I found this issue is because of using `browser.getCurrentUrl`. Let me know where I am doing wrong and would like to know deep about e2e testing with protractor.

I would like to know the basics of protractor, how it works on route change and how an async user action like `$http` is handled by protractor. Should I explicitly use promises etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you navigating to a non-angular page? If so use browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; and then change it back to false once you return to the angular page.

Comment: @KCaradonna No, it is an angular page. Working on an angular single page application

Comment: Try using browser.driver.getCurrentUrl() instead and please post results.

Comment: There is most likely something special about this "home" page - is `$timeout` or manual angular bootstrap used there?

Comment: @alecxe - There is no manual bootstrap, home is just another route. why `$timeout` can cause this issue. Could you please explain how protractor works. Does protractor waits for an async process to complete or do we need to handle it explicitly by `.then`. 
This line is an async call `element(by.buttonText('Login')).click()` and route to home page. Does protractor wait for this to complete or do we need to use promises `then`.

Comment: @KCaradonna - when I did browser.driver.getCurrentUrl(), the test is failing since it is getting the current url right away. It is not waiting for the route to complete and the test is failing instantly.

Comment: @KCaradonna It is working when I did `browser.sleep(5000)` and `expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(XXX)`. Could you explain why it worked

Comment: @KCaradonna - What is the difference browser.getCurrentUrl and browser.driver.getCurrentUrl?

Comment: You can read about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439399/protractor-browser-driver-getcurrenturl-vs-browser-getcurrenturl and for a more detailed explanation here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/634

Comment: @KCaradonna - Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an ideal world, you should not be adding any waits and `Protractor` should naturally wait for Angular to be ready and in general work in sync with it.

In a real world, unfortunately, there is often a need to add waits. Though, prefer Explicit Waits with specific conditions to hardcoded `browser.sleep()` calls which should generally be avoided. In this case, we can add a wait to wait for a specific URL, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398054/771848).

Comment: Thank You! When to use `.then` and when not use. Protractor implicitly waits for all `async` process to complete, right? So `pageObject.click(); expect(true).toBe(true)` is equal to  `pageObject.click().then(function() {  expect(true).toBe(true) })`.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @vishnu yup, you usually don't have to resolve the promises when writing protractor tests. They are put on the control flow queue, more info here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md. But, again, in corner cases using `then()` might help to tackle timing issues.

Comment: +1 for the link. What would be a corner case of using `then`. when ever I use `browser.get`, I was forced to use `browser.sleep`,  even though the page is angular.

Comment: @vishnu sure, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331499/when-should-we-use-then-with-protractor-promise.

Comment: Thanks Again! I am using `jasmine2` as the framework in protractor configuration file. But still I am not able to use `beforeAll and afterAll` as I am getting this error `ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined`. Do you have any idea.

Comment: Please try to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709893/protractor-beforeall-and-afterall-undefined

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not of `browser.getCurrentUrl()`, That piece is running fine as mentioned by you in the test which runs correctly.

Protractor gives you a big hint when it tells you `Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds`, which is its way of saying that it couldn't catch a hold of your angular page - or your angular page never finished loading in first place to take the test execution ahead. This happens when you are using either a lot of `$timeout`s or excessive polling on your page. 
To debug this problem, run your test suit with `jasmine-spec-reporter` and it will report you what function the page is waiting for (which are blocking the sync)

Answer (score 0):

[I saw this in relation to other questions somewhere else, I believe on StackOverflow. It is not original.]
What I have been doing is:

```
var EC, elm;//I have these as globals, because the issue arises a lot

EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

//after your click

elm = element(by.linkText('Logout'));//on menu at top, helps timing, 
//your next page may vary, but we have Logout only after you log in

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 20000);
expect(e2.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("data_entry");//where I say 
//data_entry you would say 
//home
```

If you think it is bad form to have multiple expectations, I suspect you could harmlessly remove the first one.
HTH