# Protractor - beforeAll and afterAll undefined

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, gulp-protractor

I am using Protractor with jasmine. Protractor version is `3.2.2`, I found this using the command `protractor --version`. How to find the jasmine version used by protractor. When I read the [updgrade doc](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/jasmine-upgrade.md#focused-specs), I couldn't find the steps to upgrade jasmine, all I found is to add `jasmine2` in configuration file.

My configuration file looks like this

```
exports.config = {  framework: 'jasmine2', .... }
```

But I still was not able to use `beforeAll and afterAll`.  Am I missing anything here. Since `beforeAll and afterAll` are undefined I think the version of jasmine used by protractor is not 2x.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can check the jasmine version that protractor uses in the file, `node_modules/protractor/package.json`

Comment: @MadhavanKumar package.json has the following as dependencies `"jasminewd2": "0.0.8", "jasmine": "2.4.1"`

Comment: Those commands are built into the jasmine frameworks so I think you're right - protractor isn't using version 2.x.  Add this to a spec and run it - console.log('jasmine-version:' + jasmine.getEnv().versionString());

Comment: What does that print?

Comment: @Gunderson - jasmine-version:1.3.1 revision 1354556913

Comment: @Gunderson - You have any idea why this is happening. How to fix this?

Comment: @vishnu First I'd try `npm update -g jasmine`, if that doesn't work my next suggestion would be to just `npm uninstall jasmine` to remove all jasmine packages completely (in case you have old ones causing conflict) then reinstall.

Comment: Also just a side note - I learned this yesterday (from alexce who answers a large portion of protractor questions on SO) - `jasmine` in your config file refers to `jasmine2` in the modern protractor.  so specifically saying `jasmine2` is not necessary - though I don't think it causes any issues if you do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109560/discussion-between-vishnu-and-gunderson).

Comment: @Gunderson - Jasmine is not installed globally.

Comment: What if you remove the `node_modules` completely, clean the cache: `npm cache clean` and run `npm install` again?

Comment: @alecxe - Is there any good resource online to learn protractor. I am `element(by.id('xxx'))` is causing the timeout error.I think protractor is not waiting for the angular to load completely on browser.get. But control flow to should handle it. I couldnt figure out whats wrong.

Comment: @alecxe - I did npm cache clean and npm install. Still the same no change in version. protractor is installed globally in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ since I am using ubuntu

Comment: @vishnu how about `npm update -g protractor`?

Answer (score 1):

Protractor 3.2.2 as of `20th April 2016` is bundled with Jasmine 2.4

A fresh install of protractor should fetch you the 2.4 version, and you can verify this while looking at the npm install dependency tree log (the npm output after it finished installing a module), search for jasmine in that tree and you should see the 2.4 version being reported.

Also, the correct config to be used is:

`framework: 'jasmine'`